# Giving the list returned by purrr::map names

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Is there a way to automatically give names to the returned list given by `purrr:map`?

For example, I run code like this very often.

```
fn <- function(x) { paste0(x, "_") }
l <- map(LETTERS, fn)
names(l) <- LETTERS
```

I'd like for the vector that is being automated upon to automatically become the names of the resulting list.

Comment: This is not an answer because it doesn't use `purrr::map`, but just to note that `base::Map` does automatically assign names as desired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `imap`

```
imap(setNames(LETTERS, LETTERS), ~ paste0(.x, "_"))
```

Or `map` with a named `vector`

```
map(setNames(LETTERS, LETTERS), ~ paste0(.x, "_"))
```

Comment: Also see `purrr::set_names`, which will name a vector with itself if no names are given: `set_names(LETTERS)`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a clean way to do it to me:

```
purrr::map(LETTERS, paste0, "_") %>% purrr::set_names()
```

Thanks to the [comment left by aosmith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726420/giving-the-list-returned-by-purrrmap-names#comment88463714_50726452) for identifying `purrr::set_names`. Note if you want to set the names to something else, just say `... %>% set_names(my_names)`.